# If you feel very comfortable to use a pen when you write something with it, that pen has______

Tags: phrase-requests

How do you say the quality of a pen,
if you feel very comfortable to use a pen when you write something with it.
I'd like to know a word or a phrase to fit into the following sentence.

> This pen has _______.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for '[ergonomics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ergonomical)', although you'd need to restructure your sentence for it to work...

Comment: Polish -  a state of high development or refinement. MW online.

Answer (score 3):

> This pen has...

a nice (or good) balance.

a nice weight.

a nice heft.

a nice (or smooth) feel.

Answer (score 0):

This pen has ***grip***.

If you feel very comfortable when writing something with this pen, then in a sense this pen gives you a *firm hold or grasp* on the subject you're writing about. The pen allows you *firm or tenacious hold, grasp, or control; power, mastery* as to what you're writing. In fact, it affords you *intellectual or mental hold; power to apprehend or master a subject*.

Italicized words are copy-and-pasted from definitions of *grip* in the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED).

Loosely, when you have a good grasp/grip on this pen, it empowers you with  an outstanding grip on what you're writing about